# How to LM Hash in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, hash, cryptography, des

OK so i have been working on this for a bit, and i cant see how to get any further. I keep running into roadblocks with the DESCryptoServiceProvider and somehow it just doesnt seem to be comming out with the right answers.

the sudo code version of LM_Hash is:

```
LMHASH = concat(DES(Upper(PWD)[0..7],KGS!@#$%),DES(Upper(PWD)[8..13],KGS!@#$%))
```

First issue is the LM Key I keep seeing the atleast two variants its either "KGS!@#$%" or "KGS!+#$%" neither gets me the right answers but both dont seem to fit with the origin story (its KGS and SHIFT 12345 assuming a US keyboard
on a UK thats "KGS!"£$%")

I am pretty sure i have the parameters set up correctly now, but my understanding seems to be failing me. here's what i have so far, any help is appreciated I am running Powershell V5.1 on Win 10, the string to encrypt is passed in as $string

```
    $plaintext = "KGS!@#$%"
    $OEM = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Host.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    $str1 = $OEM.GetBytes($string.substring(0,7)) +[Byte]$null
    $str2 = $OEM.GetBytes($string.Substring(7)) +[Byte]$null
    $IV = new-object "System.Byte[]" 8
    $hasher = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider -Property @{key=$str1; IV = $IV; mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::ECB; Padding=[System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::None}
    $outbyte = new-object "System.Byte[]" 8
    $encrypter1 = $hasher.CreateEncryptor()
    $outbyte = $encrypter1.TransformFinalBlock($OEM.GetBytes($plaintext),0,8)
    $data1 = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($outbyte).replace("-","") 
    $encrypter1.Dispose()
```

In theory this should encrypt the Key (which ever one it is) with DES using the first 7 characters of the string ($str1) as the key (with a null byte on the end) and  then we do this to the second half ($str2) and concat them back together to get the LMHASH.

Comment: Why are you fiddling around with a hash algorithm that is so fundamentally broken that it has been disabled in the default config for a decade?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am trying to get to grips with the legacy stuff before I run into greater problems trying to get NTLM to work. I am trying to put together a demo of how security has evolved and not doing very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASCII-encoded string `KGS!@#$%` is the correct magic constant to use

> using the first 7 characters of the string ($str1) as the key (with a null byte on the end)

This, however, is incorrect. The key is not composed by padding the 7 bytes of partial input with a single 0-byte at the end, but by partitioning the input into 8 7-bit chunks and left-shifting them once (resulting in 8 bytes).

The easiest way to implement this in PowerShell is probably with strings, so I'd likely do something like this:

```
# Convert string to byte array
$inBytes = $OEM.GetBytes($str1)

# Create a binary string from our bytes
$bitString = ''
foreach($byte in $inBytes){
    $bitstring += [convert]::ToString($byte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')
}

# Partition the byte string into 7-bit chunks
[byte[]]$key = $bitString -split '(?<=\G.{7}(?<!$))' |ForEach-Object {
    # Insert 0 as the least significant bit in each chunk
    # Convert resulting string back to [byte]
    [convert]::ToByte("${_}0", 2)
}

try{
    # Create the first encryptor from our new key, and an empty IV
    [byte[]]$iv = ,0 * 8
    $enc = $hasher.GetEncryptor($key, $iv)

    # Calculate half of the hash
    $block1 = $enc.TransformFinalBlock($plaintext, 0, 8)
}
finally{
    # Dispose of the encryptor
    $enc.Dispose()
}
```

Then repeat for `$str2` and concatenate the resulting blocks for the full LM hash

Comment: had to make a few minor modifications to get it to work, but thanks on the padding and confirmation of the key.

Comment: @EnviableOne nice. I also ended up writing [a full implementation here](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/50376918042912fecc5ff1402e1b7dbe).

Answer (score 0):

anyone having issues, based on [@mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)
's answer above, here is a fuction that computes half the LM-Hash takes in 7 character string and outputs the hash as Hex.

```
Function LM-hash {
    Param(
     [Parameter(mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,position=0)]
     [ValidateLength(7,7)]
     [String]$Invalue
    )
$plaintext = "KGS!@#$%"
$OEM = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Host.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
$inBytes = $OEM.GetBytes($invalue)
$bitString = ''
foreach($byte in $inBytes){
    $bitstring += [convert]::ToString($byte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')
}
[byte[]]$key = $bitString -split '(?<=\G.{7}(?<!$))' |ForEach-Object { [convert]::ToByte("${_}0", 2)}
$iv = new-object "System.Byte[]" 8
$DESCSP = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider -Property @{key=$key; IV = $IV; mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::ECB; Padding=[System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::None}
$enc = $DESCSP.CreateEncryptor()
$block1 = $enc.TransformFinalBlock($OEM.GetBytes($plaintext), 0, 8)
return [System.BitConverter]::ToString($block1).replace("-","") 
$enc.Dispose()
}
```

this gives the correct result for half the hash, so feeding each half in seperatley and concatenating the strings gives you a full LM hash